# Por que não consigo instanciar um objeto ao clicar no meu botão?

Tags: java, android

O funcionamento do botão está correto, ele executa todas as linhas anteriores. Porém, ao instanciar um objeto `Email` exibe o erro.

```
public void send(View view) {
    EditText text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    Switch iluminacao = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch1);
    Switch wifi = (Switch) findViewById(R.id.switch2);
    RatingBar mBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    System.out.println(text.getText().toString() + iluminacao.isChecked() + wifi.isChecked() + mBar.getNumStars());

    Email email = new Email();
    email.sendEmail(text.getText().toString(), iluminacao.isChecked(),
    wifi.isChecked(), mBar.getNumStars());
}
```

Classe `Email`:

```
package com.morais.daniela.conectasp;

import android.os.Build;
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
/**
 * Created by daniela on 23/03/15.
 */
public class Email {
    private SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
    //FIXME
    //Adicionar email correto para onde deverá ser enviado!
    public Email() {
        email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
        email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
        email.setSslSmtpPort("465");
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("conectasaopaulo@gmail.com.br", "senha"));
    }
    /**
     * Recebe feedbacks enviados pelo usuario e encaminha por email
     * @param comments
     * @param getIluminacao
     * @param getWifi
     * @param getStars
     */
    public void sendEmail(String comments, boolean getIluminacao, boolean getWifi, float getStars) {
        String iluminacao = "Não.";
        String wifi = "Não.";
        if (getIluminacao == true) {
            iluminacao = "Sim.";
        }
        if (getWifi == true) {
            wifi = "Sim.";
        }
        try {
            email.setFrom("conectasaopaulo@gmail.com.br");
            email.setDebug(true);
            email.setSubject("Feedback - ConectaSP");
            email.setMsg("Houve problemas com a iluminação? " + iluminacao + "\n\n" + "Houve problemas com o wifi? " + wifi + "\n\n" + "Avaliação geral " + getStars + "\n\n" + "Comentários:\n" + comments + "\n\n" + "Informações gerais do aparelho\n" + Build.DEVICE + "\t" + Build.HARDWARE + "\t" + Build.MODEL);
            email.addTo("dani.m@hotmail.co.uk");
            email.send();
        } catch (EmailException e) {
            System.err.println("Erro ao enviar email.");
        }
    }
}
```

Erro

```
03-24 12:37:36.277    4037-4037/com.morais.daniela.conectasp E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3103)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3098)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: com/morais/daniela/conectasp/Email
            at com.morais.daniela.conectasp.FeedbackActivity.send(FeedbackActivity.java:53)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3098)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3574)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14293)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4448)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:823)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:590)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Pode também informar o erro que está ocorrendo no *Logcat*?

Comment: Pronto, foi editada!

Comment: Linha 53: Email email = new Email();

Comment: Esta classe do **Apache** para envio de email que você está utilizando, ela precisa tanto do `activation.jar` e `mail.jar` do pacote **Javax**. Você os incluiu em seu projeto?

Comment: Recebi um help de que é necessário AsyncTask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniela,

Executei o seu código para testar e percebi que tem problemas na hora de autenticar.

1 - Verifique se o e-mail possui realmente é "conectasaopaulo@gmail.com.br" pois acredito que deve ser "conectasaopaulo@gmail.com", sem o ".br" no fim.

2 - Acesse a sua conta google do conectasaopaulo e crie uma autorização para aplicativos menos seguros acessar o seu e-mail, pois por padrão as suas contas do google são bloqueadas para acessos por outros aplicativos.

Para autorizar aplicativos menos seguros a acessar a conta acesse faça login na sua conta e acesse o link: https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps 
depois cliqe em ativar.

Mais informações em: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

Para autorizar acesse este link: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255

3- Exemplo do código de teste funcionando (Testado por mim).

```
    import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
    import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
    import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;
    /**
     * Created by daniela on 23/03/15.
     */

    public class Email {
        private SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
        //FIXME
        //Adicionar email correto para onde deverá ser enviado!
        public Email() {
           email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
           email.setHostName("smtp.gmail.com");
           email.setSslSmtpPort("465");
           email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator("suaconta@gmail.com", "suasenha"));

}
/**
 * Recebe feedbacks enviados pelo usuario e encaminha por email
 * @param comments
 * @param getIluminacao
 * @param getWifi
 * @param getStars
 */
public void sendEmail(String comments, boolean getIluminacao, boolean getWifi, float getStars) {
    String iluminacao = "Não.";
    String wifi = "Não.";
    if (getIluminacao == true) {
        iluminacao = "Sim.";
    }
    if (getWifi == true) {
        wifi = "Sim.";
    }
    try {
        email.setFrom("suaconta@gmail.com");
        email.setDebug(true);
        email.setSubject("Feedback - ConectaSP");
        email.setMsg("Houve problemas com a iluminação? " + iluminacao + "\n\n" + "Houve problemas com o wifi? " + wifi + "\n\n" + "Avaliação geral " + getStars + "\n\n" + "Comentários:\n" + comments + "\n\n" + "Informações gerais do aparelho\n");
        email.addTo("suaconta@gmail.com");
        email.send();
    } catch (EmailException e) {
        System.err.println("Erro ao enviar email.");
    }
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Email email = new Email();
    email.sendEmail("Comments", true,
            true, (float) 9.99);
}
```

}